# My Codeigniter site works on localhost but not on web server? 500 internal server

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, web-hosting

I have tested my website on my localhost and it is working fine and all the views/controllers and models are tested.

So I thought I would put it on my webserver and test it there, the website displays however when doing functions like

For example registering or loging into the website does not work:

I checked in firebug it is saying

500 Internal server error

Here is my site, please could you have a browse through the pages , even try registering if you like.

Another thing I noticed on the failed pages is that my favicon is changing to the root domains favicon.

[Here](http://www.iiios.eu/midas) is my actual website, its in a sub domain.

Could it be my htacces

Here is the code in it:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

I dont understand why It works on my localhost but not on a dedicated server.

They were both Apache windows servers.

Thanks, for your time.

Comment: What's in the Apache error log on the server?

Comment: How can I find that, I only have access to the sub directory where my site is in. My university provides the hosting.

Comment: Depends on the setup. I'd ask your university sysadmin if there's a way of viewing your error logs; it's a lot easier than stumbling around in the dark trying to figure out the problem without knowing what the error is.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with your routes. All your pages are with in the domain

http://www.iiios.eu/midas/*site*/register

But on registering or login it goes to

http://www.iiios.eu/midas/register

without the site in the middle and CI doesnt know how to transfer control to the route. You might wanna check your forms open and action atr for register and login form.

Update

This is your form tag. Check whether you have the method create_member on register class which is in midas directory. My guess is that you have accidentally missed the *site* there.

I think it should have been

"http://www.iiios.eu/midas/site/register/create_member"

Comment: Is this to do with my URI protocol to auto

Comment: thanks , register is a different controller to the site controller , my register controller handles registration and validation, my site controller just displays pages as a user not logged in. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This might be a problem with the routing, see if the referencing to the routes, like when registering, are correct or if you defined routes in the config.php. Is the base_url() defined correctly? Also on the homepage in the sidebar you reference a non-object property.

Comment: The undefined object is because there is no data in my database yet. Thanks.

My URI protocol is "Auto" is that what you mean. Thanks

Comment: No, I mean that when you register the URL is /site/register but when you click the button it goes to /register/create_member. I think the problem lies there, your routing! :)

Comment: register is a seperate controller , site is my controller for displaying the pages and forms like login/register. Register controller validates input with "create_member" then passes to a model 

Thanks

Comment: Then you should configure your routes in the config.php because calling /site/register does not call two controllers in the code. It goes like: /controller/function/id

So if you want to call the controller when registring you should define the rout something like this: $route["site/register/create_member"] = "register/create_member"; This makes the url refer to the register-controller and then the function create_member. :)

Comment: Thanks for explaining, I am still confused. My site controller displays the register and login pages e.g. site/register or site/login  . However when you register it should switch to midas/register/create_member

Comment: That's what it does, but giving the fact that you get the error, it means that the controllers are not in place, otherwise you wouldn't get the error.. :)